# Multithreaded State Machine Implementation in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, embedded-linux

We have a design for a software, with different threads: one thread is listening on a socket for incoming requests, and depending on the request should send an event to be read by the state machine thread.

The state machine thread reads the event, performs an action (most of the time notifying another thread or spawning one), and waits for new events.

I've been checking epoll, but I have also read about boost being helpful to implement this. Any suggestion?

This is being programmed on an embedded Linux system.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us your attempt(s) so far, and why they haven't worked?

Comment: use pthread library. It is available in C and most probably in C++.

Comment: I am using pthreads for my threads, but I am more curious on how would be the ideal implementation for the communication between them.

Comment: Well, a producer-consumer queue, presumably.  condvar+mutex.

Comment: There is no language "C/C++". Pick one, that will greatly influence the implementation and architecture.

Answer (score 1):

For threads: std::thread or boost::thread

For socket I/o: boost::asio

For state machines: boost::statechart or boost::msm

Absolutely everything you need in one fantastic library.

Comment: Hmm... great.  If only it answered the question:(

Comment: @MartinJames The op asked for a suggestion. That's the only question in the question. Boost comes with comprehensive documentation. I'm sure he's a bright chap and can take it from there. What else can I say? He hasn't asked for a design outline. If he did, his question would be closed off as off topic.